# How to add formating to mailR body of mail

Tags: r

I am trying to send a mail about using `mailR`package, but as it is quite complicated issue, I would like to add a bit of formaring:

1. "Do not cut this forest!" should be bold
2. Numbered list should be nicely formatted

.

```
library(mailR) # library used to send mails

# The text I would like to send:
Text <- "Hi! 

Do not cut this forest!

The reason for this  ar as follows:
1. Trees are good
2. bla bla bla

best regards,
MS"

#In reality I am reading it from TXT file
text_real <- readChar('text_real.txt', file.info('text_real.txt')$size)
text_real <- enc2utf8(text_real)

sender <- ...
recipients <- ...
password <- ...
title <- "title"


#Sending mail
send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = title,
          body = Text,
          encoding = "utf-8",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = sender,            
                      passwd = password, ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Alternativly I know that `mailR` is using `html` so I have written it all in World and saved is as html. Unfortunatly it didn't work and coused seccond problem

```
Text <- paste(readLines("real text.htm"), collapse="\n")
```

1. body of mail in fact send::

   < html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
   xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
   xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
   xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
   ...
2. I need to personalise every mail, in first solution (the `txt` one) I have used simple `gsub` function and I believe it will not be working here.

I have also tried adding to `TXT` file, html formatting (`<b>` and `<strong>`) manually, but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a html was correct, but you don't read it into R. `send.mail()`can send html-files as body.

```
library(mailR)

send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = title,
          body = "path-to-html-file",  #pass the file
          html = TRUE,                #tell send.mail you're using html
          encoding = "utf-8",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = sender,            
                      passwd = password, ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```